# Center UIButtons in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I am trying to add a number of buttons into a horizontal scrolling `UIScrollView`. Currently I have some problems positioning my buttons in this `UIScrollView`.

**I want to achieve the following effect:**

- Buttons should be center-aligned within the UIScrollView
- If the buttons exceed the UIScrollView frame the UIScrollView should be horizontally scrollable
- In both portrait and landscape mode, the buttons have to be positioned correctly

This is what I currently have:
[image: portrait]
[image: landscape]

I guess my best option is to add AutoLayout to the buttons. Any clue for me on this one ?

Here is my code relevant to this issue:

```
   class SeasonNavigatorScrollView: UIScrollView {
    private let kButtonSize:CGFloat = 50.0
    private let kSpacing:CGFloat = 10.0
    private var buttons:[UIButton] = []
    var seasonNavigatorDelegate:SeasonNavigatorDelegate?

    func setup(count:Int) {
        self.contentSize = CGSizeMake((kButtonSize+kSpacing)*CGFloat(count), self.bounds.size.height)
        for i in 0..<count {
            let button = UIButton(type: .Custom)
            button.setTitle("\(i+1)", forState:.Normal)
            button.setTitleColor(.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
            button.tag = i
            button.layer.cornerRadius = kButtonSize/2
            button.frame = CGRectMake((kButtonSize+kSpacing)*CGFloat(i), 0, kButtonSize, kButtonSize)
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            button.addTarget(self, action: "didClickSeason:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            buttons.append(button)
            self.addSubview(button)
        }

        if count > 0 {
            self.animateButtonSelection(buttons[0])
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Here are some picture which might clarify what I am looking for:

**1:**

[image: 1 element]

**2:**

[image: 2 elements]

**Multiple:**

[image: multiple elements]

Thanks,
David

**EDIT 2:** 
First of all thanks to @OmkarGuhilot the solution worked partly for me but I had problems when I added more buttons than fitting in my self.view.bounds. The FlowLayout subclass would then make a second row instead of providing the possibility to scroll horizontally.

Here is my solution which works as intended:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
        insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
            let totalCellWidth:CGFloat =  50.0 * CGFloat(self.seasons.count)
            let viewWidth:CGFloat = self.seasonNavigator.bounds.size.width
            let totalSpacingWidth:CGFloat = 10 * (CGFloat(self.seasons.count)-1)
            print(viewWidth)
            let leftInsets = (viewWidth - (totalCellWidth + totalSpacingWidth)) / 2
            let rightInsets = leftInsets

            return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, max(leftInsets,10), 0, max(rightInsets,10))
    }

    override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        self.seasonNavigator.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }
```

Comment: why don't you use a collection view ? it would also handle the scrolling by itself

Comment: because the UICollectionView FlowLayout also begins on the left side and does not center the items.. ?

Comment: Do you want it in a way that the first item will be in center and then when you scroll them the selected item would remain in center and the rest would scroll horizontally ?

Comment: Something like a horizontal picker view ?

Comment: @OmkarGuhilot please see my edited question

Comment: collection view combined with this library would solve your issue https://github.com/keighl/KTCenterFlowLayout

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. If you add this comment as an answer I could reward you with some points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use collection view combined with https://github.com/keighl/KTCenterFlowLayout

This would also handle the scroll by itself and it would make it easier

Thanks

Omkar

Comment: Thanks I had problems with this solution but I found a solution on my own. I still accept this answer since it probably will be the right answer for people with a similar problem like mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put your buttons in a subview, adapt subview's constraints to your buttons and apply a contraint "center horizontally" from your subView to your scrollView.

[storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9PXj.png)

[portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3VhX.png)